# Page Performance in IE7 with a large page

Tags: asp.net, javascript, css, performance, internet-explorer-7

Ok so I'm writing a failry complex ASP.NET page that has quite a bit of javascript related to it.  The problem is the page has alot going on with it but the browser just acts unresponsive alot of the time and lags while the javascript seems to perform fine.

In this page, I send down a array list of available items for the user to select from.  Well when this list grows to like a 1000+ items in the list the page just sucks for lack of better words.  If i don't have that many items to select from the page acts fine.  I mean the javascript performance is ok but the page just lags.  The scroll bars on the page are just laggy, it just feels like horrible.  Of course none of this happens in Chrome or Firefox.

To kind of give you a little more perspective on the issue, the site has about 150k unminified uncompress css styles for this page, about 10,000 lines of code for js including frameworks, controls, and business rules specific for the page, and the array object text saved to a text document is about 200kb.

Any help on the matter would be greatly appeciated as this is about my 5th month stab at getting this faster...

Comment: What exactly does the page do?  I can't imagine giving you any relevant advice without more information, other than you have a clear need to simplify.

Comment: Have you done any tests to make sure that it's definitely the javascript causing the problem?  Ie, have you tried removing the CSS reference completely?

Also, are there any tables on the page?

Answer (score 1):

One of the [Yahoo performance rules](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) is "Reduce the number of DOM elements". They say this for a reason.

When you start to go into the range of "thousands" of DOM elements, IE bogs down pretty rapidly. Every interaction with the page becomes slow. The only "solution" is to use fewer DOM elements.

For example, I recently made a web app containing 4 grids with 100 rows each with around 10 columns, all visible at the same time. Those 4000 cells were making IE really slow. I solved this by using a buffered view grid, that only renders the visible rows, and removes the rows outside of the visible scroll area from the DOM (using the ExtJS grid if it interests you).

Answer (score 0):

> Of course none of this happens in Chrome or Firefox.

The bane of my little web app developer existence once things get awesome.  There's no answer usually other than to simplify the page.

The concepts behind pagination apply to other application pieces.  Active Directory won't display every record in a single list once it's large--and it's a desktop app.

Cut it back and then use the interface to get things gradually (usually through JSON requests for me).